# Pushing near real time data in a Java WebApp

Tags: java, performance, web-applications, push-notification, push

There is this java web application with a lot of users. These users place some orders according to the data shown in their panels. The data is being updated second by second by calling an outsider service (via a webservice or so). The moment we get this data, users' panels must be updated immediately to make sure that users are placing valid orders.

So we need to push data to the client WebApp. Performance and reliability are of great concern. 
What approach or technology do you suggest here? Should I use somthing like Comets? Or is using primitive WebSockets suitable?

Comment: websockets are a great place to begin with. you said web app. as in a product. or just a web page. If it is a product, go with web sockets as you don't have to worry about browser compatibility issues or anything.

Comment: Web Socket implementations on the Web server are something to consider though. Unless you use a library like Atmosphere, the code you write will most likely conform the Web socket specs of a particular Web Server

Comment: Yeah I'd say websockets. By the sound of your demands, forget SOAP, REST, long-pulling  and other nighthacks.

Comment: Just know that your users may face a lot of issues when sitting behind a proxy who may have a problem with the protocol upgrade process.

Comment: @MartinAndersson: SOAP and other WS implementations are definitely a lousy choice here. And thank you for mentioning potential problems with proxies. More info (for further readers) : http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers

Answer (score 1):

Websocket is the fastest transport but it's not supported well (by old versions of Internet Explorer).

AJAX requests are not that fast (because browser potentially will establish new HTTP connection and HTTP headers introduce overhead too) but much better supported. And with correct keep-alive settings HTTP connection should be reused.

You can use some generic implementation like sock.js (well supported by Spring framework). It'll choose the best available transport automatically. But it introduces an additional layer of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of things to consider.

There are various technologies. You've mentioned Comet. There is also Web Sockets. Without support at the protocol level, you are stuck with pretty much polling for data. This is the approach Comet takes.

Web Sockets is specifically designed for this. It has far less overhead than a TCP or UDP based message stream.

Are you targeting modern browsers or also need to support older browsers?

There is varied support for protocols, across versions, implementations may have some caveats and so on.

> Or is using primitive WebSockets suitable?

It is perfectly acceptable. Though you have to deal with variances with browser differences, or you may find porting your web sockets across web servers may require some work.

For instance, if you are deploying on Jetty (and using its API natively), you need to implement [WebSocketCreator](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.6.v20141205/jetty-websocket-server-api.html). If you are using Grizzly natively, you need to implement [WebSocketListener](https://grizzly.java.net/websockets.html) and so on.

[Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) tries to fix this by providing a uniform interface which works across various servers. Again, once you pick such a library, you will need to make changes if you want a different library in the future.

Or you could do use a service like Pusher or any of its competitors.

If you Google around, you should be able to find plenty of examples.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I need one single example that says websockets are not portable =) Adding dependencies on third party libraries require real reasons. Remember what Donald Knuth said: "premature optimization is the root of all evil". I consider "premature problemsolving" the same thing. I know that some browsers had an issue with pings and pongs in the beginning but I think that is solved now. What I do know is that the websocket channel used in my own [chat application](http://www.martinandersson.com) work perfectly fine across all browsers.

Comment: I guess, I was talking about the server implementation. I made an edit, and hopefully my intent is clearer. Suppose you choose to deploy on Grizzly. Grizzly has its own interface to enable WebSockes. Similarly there are separate ones for Jetty and other web servers. If he want to support all of them, he'll have to implement all those interface.

Comment: additionally, Web Sockets aren't support across all browsers+versions. Have a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets. Version which are not green or before the green ones don't support WebSockets. You have to use Long Polling or other techniques. If you prepare a sample and test it across modern current browsers, they should all work.

Comment: Me personally, I value my time more than a minority of all users on old browsers. Try to turn of JavaScript and see how much of internet still work. Not much. I think that trying to be backward compatible is an illusion and waste of time. We should spend our precious time on modern technology instead and write better applications more powerful that suite the needs for more users. Just my opinion =) Also, one shouldn't tie his application to particular implementations if there exist a standardized API, like [Java API for WebSocket](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356).

Comment: Thank you @Nasir. I don't think portability across servers would be a problem in my case. Your answer helped but i'm gonna keep the thread open for a while to see if there are other opinions.

Comment: @MartinAndersson: Unfortunately we live in a cruel world in which some human beings are still using IE7 or even 6 (in win XP)! But I am on your side on spending time more on better apps than silly browser compatibility for old bags.